# How to create a rectangular label that acts like a marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have created a number of google maps using markers, polygons, etc. Now, I am trying to create a map using a marker that displays content ON the marker. Google has a demo of this http://www.morethanamap.com/demos/places

Here is picture of what I am referring to: [image]

You will note the rectangles with red or white backgrounds. If you go to the link I provided, you will find that these labels also function as markers. Which is exactly what I am looking for. However, I cannot find any documentation (or example code) on how to do this. There is a icongenerator for Android yet I do not find any comparable function for web based applications.

So, if anyone can point me in the correct direction or provide a code snippet it would be appreciated.

Shimon

Comment: Are you looking something like [this] (http://www2.uah.es/jcaceres/capsulas/java_modografico.pdf)

Comment: I don't see there anything with red background, but when you mean white/green, these are clickable labels, they are coming from the default-map(usually they will be called POI). You may use a library like [markerWithLabel](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerwithlabel/1.1.9/docs/reference.html) to create such labels(to get there only the label and not the marker you may use a transparent image as marker-icon)

Comment: I am red/green color blind, so you may be correct!

Comment: Dr.Molle, markerWithLabel adds a label to a marker so that you end up with a label AND a marker. I only want a label that functions like a marker as in the example above.